# Git how to give people push access that needs to be merged in by organizers?

Tags: git, github

My project has quite a few people and I want to give them all push & pull access because right now, they forked the project and when they make changes, they have to push to their fork and send me a pull request. Instead, I want them to be able to clone the main project at `myusername/project` and be able to push to it automatically.
So how would I do that?

Comment: How is this related to github?

Comment: @AndrewMyers I was thinking that you could somehow do it with github. I'm new to this so I don't know

Comment: What's wrong with forks and pull requests? They are precisely how you would manage requiring approval for a push to be accepted.

Comment: @cjc343 Yes, but I want to add them as collaborators to the project, so they would have direct push access instead of pushing to their own fork and then sending a pull request.

Comment: A collaborator won't require your permission to push commits to your repo. How exactly do you plan to manage the acceptance or rejection of commits if they are being pushed directly to the project by collaborators? You get one or the other, not both. If they are collaborators, there is no approval process for them to push commits. If they are not, then you have an approval process. Why is it important they not use forks and pull requests?

Comment: @cjc343 i just find it annoying when they have to go onto github.com each time and press pull request when they'll have to push quite frequently

Comment: GitHub has an API that allows you to create & modify Pull Requests. The solution does not provide for "[you] will have to look at the pushes and merge them in [your]self". Your question suggests that you do not completely trust your 'collaborators' to not force push a bare repo (or attempt to sneak in malicious changes), but you'll be giving them the ability to do so. Best of luck with your repo, I hope you avoid adding anyone with malicious intent.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

1. Ask for the username of the person you're adding as a collaborator. If they don't have one, they can [sign up for GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/signing-up-for-a-new-github-account).
2. In the top right corner of any page, click your username.
3. On your profile page, click the **Repositories** tab, then click the name of your repository.
4. In your repository's right sidebar, click **Settings**.
5. Click the "Collaborators" tab.
6. Start typing the collaborator's username.
7. Select the user from the drop-down menu.
8. Click **Add**.

Comment: Looks like it's now Settings --> Manage Access --> "Invite a collaborator". Please update your answer.

Comment: Settings --> Manage Access --> Invite teams or people