# Implementation of several views in one recyclerViews

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I implement different views in one recyclerViews in Kotlin ???

I want to create an application containing legal codes. My problem is that individual legal provisions are divided into chapters. And if I can create a progran that will display all the recipes for me, I don't really know how to put it in the recyclerView between the layout with specific legal provisions layout with information about the number and title of the chapter.

The code below still shows me the same view.

```
package pl.nynacode.naukapraw
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.cart_view_legal_name.view.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.chapter_layout.view.*

class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>(){
    class MyViewHolder(val view: View, val view2: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val layoutInflater= LayoutInflater.from(parent.context);
        val legalName = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_view_legal_name, parent ,false);
        val chapterName = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chapter_layout, parent,false);
        return MyViewHolder(legalName, chapterName);
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return KodeksKarny.nrArticle.size;
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when(position){
            0->{
                val chapter = holder.view2.tvChapterName;
                chapter.setText(KodeksKarny.nrArticle[position])
            }
            else->{
                val nrArticle = holder.view.nrArt;
                val textArticle=holder.view.txtArt;

                nrArticle.setText(KodeksKarny.nrArticle[position]);
                textArticle.setText(KodeksKarny.txtArticle[position]);

                // obsługa klikniecia na przycisk
                nrArticle.setOnClickListener{
                    if (textArticle.visibility == View.GONE){
                        textArticle.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    }else textArticle.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I will add that I'm a beginner and I can't do much yet

Comment: OK.  I have already done

Answer (score 1):

`RecyclerView.Adapter` has a method called `fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int` that returns the type of view on a given position.

Based on that function you can create different view holders or pass to the same view holder type different layouts (but avoid last one).

You simply need to override a function in your adapter and decide the type of an item at that position:

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    val item = getItem(position)
    // the code below is just an example. 
    val type = when (item) {
        is Header -> HEADER_TYPE
        is NotHeader -> NOT_HEADER_TYPE
    }
    return type
}
```

Where you could define these types? In companion object for example:

```
class YourAdapter: ... {
    companion object {
        private const val HEADER_TYPE = 0
        private const val NOT_HEADER_TYPE = 1
    }

    ...
}
```

Later in `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` you can create different view holders and bind to those view holders the data you have.

```
class YourAdapter: ... {
    companion object {
        private const val HEADER_TYPE = 0
        private const val NOT_HEADER_TYPE = 1
    }

    ...
    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val item = getItem(position)
        // the code below is just an example. 
        val type = when (item) {
            is Header -> HEADER_TYPE
            is NotHeader -> NOT_HEADER_TYPE
        }
        return type
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        if (viewType == HEADER_TYPE) {
            // Here you create HeaderViewHolder
        } else {
            val layoutInflater= LayoutInflater.from(parent.context);
            val legalName = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_view_legal_name, parent ,false);
            val chapterName = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chapter_layout, parent,false);
            return MyViewHolder(legalName, chapterName);
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val itemViewType = getItemViewType(position)
        if (itemViewType == HEADER_TYPE) {
            // cast MyViewHolder to HeaderViewHolder, for example
            val header = viewHolder as HeaderViewHolder
            header.headerTitle.text = ...
        } else {
            val nrArticle = holder.view.nrArt;
            ... other type
        }

    }
}
```

[Here are the official tutorials](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-headers/#0) on how to create an adapter with different types of views.

What I personally prefer is to implement `abstract class BaseViewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder` that will be used as a generic type argument of your adapter implementation. This `BaseViewHolder` should have an abstract method, like `abstract fun bind(data: YourDataType)`. The function will be implemented by view holders that will extend the `BaseViewHolder` class.

Also, as Kotlin provides us with sealed classes I prefer to create a sealed class and objects that extend from it to hold view holder types so when you implement your `onCreateViewHolder` method it could avoid `else` case. But that is just what I like and is not required in any way.

An example of `sealed class` + `object`s + `onCreateViewHolder`:

```
sealed class Types(val rawType: Int) {
    object Header: Types(0)
    object NotHeader: Types(1)

    companion object {
       fun from(rawType: Int) = 
           when (rawType) {
               Header.rawType -> Header
               NotHeader.rawType -> NotHeader
               else -> throw RuntimeException("No such type")
           }
    }
}

class YourAdapter ... {

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        val item = getItem(position)
        // the code below is just an example. 
        val type = when (item) {
            is Header -> Types.Header.rawType
            is NotHeader -> Types.NotHeader.rawType
        }
        return type
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder =
        when (Types.from(viewType)) {
            is Types.Header -> // return HeaderViewHolder
            is Types.NotHeader -> // return NotHeaderViewHolder
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use your tip, but I don't think I have enough skills to understand it.

And the code still doesn't work

Comment: Try to follow [this detailed tutorial from Google](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-headers/#0) on how to create an adapter that is able to produce multiple different views. It may take at least 30 minutes to finish. But it presents the same idea as in my answer.

Comment: I did as directed and did the Google tutorial. The tutorial application is quite extensive. Uses the code from previous lessons. Although the code from the lesson works as it should, I still don't know how to use it in my case. By the way, thank you for your patience and willingness to help.

Comment: @MatiR, you are welcome! If you can upload your application to GitHub or similar I could create a few push requests to help you out just for the sake of explanation.

Comment: Ok. This is my project: https://github.com/matir85/LearningRecyclerView

Comment: @MatiR, add me as a collaborator to this GitHub repository. My username is JeneaVranceanu. I'm ready to show you the result so you could understand how it works. Here is how to add me as a collaborator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14972607/7210237

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would have one more request. Could you describe your changes and how should I understand them ????

Comment: I'll describe them on GitHub.

Comment: Maybe we'll switch to some messenger. I have some questions about learning Android and do not want to litter this thread.

Comment: Open an issue on GitHub. It will be enough and publicly visible.