# How to add Header in RecyclerView Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, header

I made a simple mockup app that contains a recyclerView GridView. But I find it hard to learn how to add Header. Since most of the tutorials aren't clear and based on Java.

**How do I add a header?** I can not find a decent or clear tutorial concerning this.
Please help.

This is the activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var items: ArrayList<Item>
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        items = ArrayList()
        recyclerView_activityMain.adapter = MainAdapter(items)
    }
}
```

This is the adapter **Main Adapter**

```
class MainAdapter(val item: ArrayList<Item>): RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.layout_card_view, parent, false)
        return CustomViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.view.apply {
            cardView_textView.text = "dummy text"
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return 12
    }

}

class Item(val text: String) {
    constructor(): this("")
}

class CustomViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
```

Comment: what do you mean by header? if you want to have something displayed on top of the list at all times it's best to put it outside of the `RecyclerView`, whatever is in the list will be moving when you scroll

Comment: @Stachu A header is a view that also moves with the recyclerView layout. Coding it outside the recyclerView adapter will make the view unable to follow the scrolling movement of the recyclerView.

Comment: Please refer to this video [link](http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/10/adding-header-and-footer-layouts-for.html)

Comment: @Branddd, recycler view allows you to have multiple types of view holder. Here is an example with explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62363549/7210237

Comment: @Branddd, please consider closing this question if an answer from another post helped you. It will prevent other people from posting answers here and spending their time on a question that was already answered. Thank you!