# How to give a user a write access to a PR?

Tags: github, pull-request

I'm trying to contribute to a project on Github so i made a fork of the staging branch and edited it then submited a PR, then somone wanted to do some edits on my PR instead of creating a whole new PR so how can i give him this permision. Im wondering should i give that user a write permision to my forked project/branch or to the PR directly, and how can i do that.

Comment: Duplicate of [Adding a collaborator to my free GitHub account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920320/adding-a-collaborator-to-my-free-github-account)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969281/git-how-to-give-people-push-access-that-needs-to-be-merged-in-by-organizers

Answer (score 0):

You may add that user as a collaborator to your personal forked repository from the settings of that repository. When the user pushes to the branch you created the PR from, the PR will also be updated.

Steps to add collaborators to your personal repo:

1. Ask for the username of the person you're inviting as a collaborator.
2. On GitHub Enterprise, navigate to the main page of the repository.
3. Under your repository name, click Settings.
4. In the left sidebar, click Collaborators.
5. Under "Collaborators", start typing the collaborator's username.
6. Select the collaborator's username from the drop-down menu.
7. Click Add collaborator.

See Inviting [Collaborators to a personal repository](https://help.github.jp/enterprise/2.11/user/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/).